# Where can I find drivers for my new Toshiba L665 laptop?

Tags: drivers, toshiba-laptop

I just bought a Toshiba L665 laptop and I can't find the drivers anywhere online. Where can I find the toshiba driver repo and find what I need for this specific model?

Comment: Why do you need drivers for a brand new laptop? Are you downgrading the OS? Just curious.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the toshiba website itself?

http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/home.jsp?nav=Download

Choose your laptop from the list and click GO. It has a lot of L665 models on there, so you will need to find out your submodel number.